# Return aud from AWS Cognito refresh_token results

Tags: amazon-cognito, koa

I am using AWS Cognito for authenticating users.

I have created a server using Kosjs and used koa-jwt library to verify if users have valid id_tokens.

koa-jwt expects an **aud** property in the id_token which initially exists in the id_token returned by AWS Cognito.

But when I use the refresh token to get a new token, the new token contains **client_id** instead of **aud**.

Because of this, the koa-jwt doesn't verify the id_token anymore.

Is there any way to get a consistent result from AWS Cognito?

This is the sample id_token after login:

```js
{
  "sub": "1Xfe6c44-XXXX-4cbf-9fb2-2778a1b0e5be",
  "email_verified": true,
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ap-northeast-1_xxxOUKTJu",
  "phone_number_verified": true,
  "cognito:username": "oqtz@n.spamtrap.co",
  "given_name": "Some1",
  "aud": "xxxxf9f0lmr1q6ni2c09umdds",
  "event_id": "9cf03730-xxxx-11e9-a89f-67080ff7c936",
  "token_use": "id",
  "auth_time": 1546931916,
  "phone_number": "+16806666986",
  "exp": 1546935516,
  "iat": 1546931916,
  "family_name": "Some2",
  "email": "oqtz@n.spamtrap.co"
}
```

and this is the sample id_token returned by refresh_token:

```js
{
  "sub": "16fe6c44-xxxx-xxxx-9fb2-2778a1b0e5be",
  "event_id": "9cf03730-xxxx-xxxx-a89f-67080ff7c936",
  "token_use": "access",
  "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin",
  "auth_time": 1546931916,
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ap-northeast-1_xxxxxKTJu",
  "exp": 1546939290,
  "iat": 1546935690,
  "jti": "6fab7b58-xxxx-xxxx-a339-ddb6467e2d4c",
  "client_id": "xxxxx9f0lmr1q6ni2c09umdds",
  "username": "oqtz@n.spamtrap.co"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully tested things with refresh, but I got the basics working quickly by following the example at the bottom of [this section](https://github.com/koajs/jwt#token-verification-exceptions) on the koa-jwt readme.

```
const { koaJwtSecret } = require('jwks-rsa');

    app.use(jwt({   
        secret: <any> koaJwtSecret({
            jwksUri: `https://cognito-idp.${config.userPoolRegion}.amazonaws.com/${config.userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
            cache: true,
            cacheMaxEntries: 5,
            cacheMaxAge: 36000000 ///10 hr 
        }) 
    }));
```

Comment: Sure that works, but it skips checking audience, issuer and algorithms:
Your jwt options should look like this:
    const jwtOptions = {
        secret: koaJwtSecret({
            jwksUri: process.env.ADMIN_IDP_JWKS_URI!,
            cache: true,
            rateLimit: true,
        }),
        algorithms: ['RS256'],
        audience: process.env.ADMIN_IDP_AUDIENCE,
        issuer: process.env.ADMIN_IDP_ISSUER,
    };